Understanding change of momentum during collisions
Following this question, I felt a little bit uncomfortable:
It deals with a case of two equal masses $A, B$ so that $A$'s speed is $v$ and $B$ stays at rest. Then A moves horizontally toward $B$ until it collides.
I understand, by the inertial frame notion presented in the question linked above, that we can derive that $A$'s speed after the collision would be $\frac{1}{2}v$.
However I do not understand why it follows by the example presented that it would also be the speed of the masses $A,B$ as one if they both stick together after the collision (as claimed in the question).
I'll be glad if someone could help me with some intuition about it.

It's a Galilean transformation:
$$ x' = x + u t $$
$$ t' = t $$
where as per canon, the unprimed frame is at rest, and the primed frame is moving.
So the initial state is:
$$ x_A(t) = v t$$
$$ x_B(t) = -v t $$
so that:
$$ v_A = \frac{dX_A}{dt} = v $$
$$ v_B = \frac{dX_B}{dt} = -v $$
i.e., equal and opposite velocities.
They collide at $t=0$, after which:
$$ x_A(t) = x_B(t) = 0 \equiv x_{AB}(t)$$
Now apply the Galilean transformation with $u=v$, to the initial state:
$$ x'_A(t') = (v_A t) + (ut) = 2vt' $$
$$ x'_B(t') = (v_B t) + (ut) = (v-v)t = 0 $$
while after the collision:
$$ x'_{AB}(t') = x_{AB}(t) + ut = vt' $$
so:
$$ v'_{AB} = \frac{dx'_{AB}}{dt'}  = v $$
That is, the lump moves at half the initial speed of the moving mass.
Edit: Note that this problem becomes fun if we consider relativity, and let the energy of the inelastic collision become internal energy of the $AB$ lump (mass $M$).
With that, the initial energy ($c=1$) is in the COM frame:
$$ E_i = \gamma m + \gamma m = 2\gamma m $$
$$ E_f = M \gt 2m $$
so the final mass is:
$$M = 2\gamma m $$
This could be heat, or vibrations. I like to imagine it's an ideal clamped thought-experiment spring that contains the excess energy as potential energy.
Now we boost that to the moving frame so that $B$ is stationary:
$$ v'_B = 0 $$
We need to use the relativistic velocity addition to get:
$$ v'_A = \frac{2v}{1+v^2} \lt 2v $$
The initial momentum is ($p'_B=0$):
$$ p'_i = p'_A = \frac{mv'_A}{\sqrt{1-v'^2_A}}$$
$$ p'_i =
2m\frac
{\frac v {1+v^2}}
{\sqrt{1-\frac{4v^2}{(1+v^2)^2}}}$$
$$ p'_i = \frac{2mv}{\sqrt{
(1+v^2)^2 - 4v^2
}}$$
$$ p'_i = \frac{2mv}{\sqrt{
(1+2v^2+ (v^2)^2 - 4v^2
}}$$
$$ p'_i = \frac{2mv}{\sqrt{
(1-2v^2+ (v^2)^2}}$$
$$ p'_i = \frac{2mv}{\sqrt{
(1-v^2)^2
}} = \frac{2mv}{1-v^2}$$
$$ p'_i = 2\gamma^2mv$$
and the final momentum is that of the $AB$ lump:
$$ p'_f = \gamma Mv $$
$$ p'_f = \gamma(2m\gamma)v$$
$$p'_f = 2\gamma^2 mv $$
so you need $E=mc^2$ and relativistic velocity addition to conserve momentum:
$$p'_f = p'_i$$
very cool.


I understand, by the inertial frame notion presented in the question
linked above, that we can derive that $A$'s speed after the collision
would be $\frac{1}{2}v$.

This describes a perfectly inelastic head on collision between an initially  moving body and a body initially at rest .
A perfectly inelastic collision is one in which the maximum amount of kinetic energy is lost consistent with conservation of momentum. In this case, in order for momentum to be conserved the velocity of $B$, measured in the same reference frame as that in which the velocity of $A$ is measured, would also be $\frac{1}{2}v$.

However I do not understand why it follows by the example presented
that it would also be the speed of the masses $A,B$ as one if they
both stick together after the collision (as claimed in the question).

Since both $A$ and $B$ have the same final velocity (magnitude and direction) after the collision, it follows that they must be moving together.
Hope this helps.

Always thought that in perfectly elastic collision no KE was lost.

@Rich of course. I meant inelastic. Corrected. Thanks
